# (C++ Beginner) How do I call these class functions into the main?

Tags: c++, function, class, oop

I keep having errors, I'm not sure how to call this Car class into the main function. The instructions I was given are below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Car{
public:

Car(){
    int year = 1990;
    std::string make = "Bentley";
    int speed = 0;
};

Car(int new_year, std::string new_make, int new_speed) {
     year = new_year;
     make = new_make;
     speed = new_speed;
}

int get_year() { return year; }
std::string get_make() { return make; }
int get_speed() { return speed; }

void accelerate() {
    speed+=5;
}

void brake() {
    speed-=5;
}

private:
int year;
std::string make;
int speed;
};

int main()
{
int year = 1990;
std::string make = "Bentley";
int speed = 0;

Car YourCar(year, make, speed);

std::cout << "Year: " << YourCar.get_year << std::endl;
std::cout << "Make: " << YourCar.get_make << std::endl;
std::cout << "Speed: " << YourCar.get_speed << std::endl;
}
```

Instructions:
Please implement a class named Car in C++ that has the following member
variables:

1. year. An int that holds the car’s model year.
2. make. A string object that holds the make of car.
3. speed. An int that holds the car’s current speed.
   In addition, the class should have the following member functions:
4. Constructor. The constructor should accept the car’s year and make
   as arguments and assign these values to the object’s year and make
   member variables. The constructor should initialize the speed member
   variable to 0.
5. Accessors or Getters. Appropriate accessors or getters should allow
   values to be retrieved from an object’s year, make and speed member
   variables.
6. accelerate. The accelerate function should add 5 to the speed member
   variable each time it’s called.
7. brake. The brake function should subtract 5 from the speed member
   variable each time it is called.

Demonstrate the class in a program that creates a Car object and then
calls the accelerate function 5 times. After each call to the accelerate function,
get the current speed of the car and display it. Then, call the brake
function 5 times. After each call to the break function, get the current speed
of car and display it.

Comment: do your own homework.  If you have a specific problem, describe it with a minimal case that represents your issue.

Comment: Alex, it is at the end of the semester buddy. You gotta do your homework. However, first initialize the class, Car *car = new Car();

Comment: This constructor is written as if in JavaScript. C++ (and most other languages) work very differently.

Comment: @JaredBurrows No, that would be Java. He did at least create the `Car` correctly.

Comment: @JaredBurrows .;..what? what would `Car *car = new Car()` possibly help with?

Comment: @Potatoswatter and immibis, oops. I didn't scroll down all the way. I saw "class functions into the main".

Comment: Wow @alex... what a way to talk to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Car(){
    int year = 1990;
    std::string make = "Bentley";
    int speed = 0;
};
```

to

```
Car(){
     year = 1990;
     make = "Bentley";
     speed = 0;
}
```

You don't need to specify the data type here.

next,

```
std::cout << "Year: " << YourCar.get_year << std::endl;
std::cout << "Make: " << YourCar.get_make << std::endl;
std::cout << "Speed: " << YourCar.get_speed << std::endl;
```

Should be

```
std::cout << "Year: " << YourCar.get_year() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Make: " << YourCar.get_make() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Speed: " << YourCar.get_speed() << std::endl;
```

You forgot the `()` after the functions.

Comment: I don't think C++ will really ever complain about too many semicolons.

Comment: Actually the constructor should probably accept parameters and not initialize all cars the same, I suppose.

Comment: The constructor is overloaded.

Comment: @Wug Ah, I see, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's all the help I need to fix this up.

Comment: @Wug , you were right about the semicolon, I didn't know about this feature.